# Google GA4 Report for Event with Event Parameter

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, reporting, google-analytics-4, event-tracking

Here is my GTM Configuration for an event.

[image]

Now I want create a report in GA4, were I can see in rows the values of popular_categories with event count for that value. How can I do that? I have already about 1000 clicks with Popular Categories Event. I can see it under Property Configuration -> Events. But in my report I can see only Popular Categories event count and not the event parameter values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, per [GA4's event naming rules](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/13316687?hl=en), I recommend changing your tag's event name from **Popular Categories** to **popular_categories_link_click**.

Then, you'll need to create a custom dimension to start seeing data for your **popular_categories** event parameter.

To create the custom dimension,

1. Open your GA4 property.
2. Mouse over the left-hand menu and click **Admin**.
3. In the **Property** column, click **Custom definitions**.
4. In the top-right corner, click the blue **Create custom dimension** button.
5. For the **Dimension name** field, enter something like **Popular categories title**.
6. For the **Scope** field, choose **Event**.
7. Skip the **Description** field.
8. For the **Event parameter** field, enter **popular_categories**.
9. Wait 24-48 hours to start seeing data for this custom dimension in GA4.

Custom dimensions are not retroactive, so you'll only be able to see **popular_categories** event parameter data from this point onward.

To see this data, use a Report or Exploration with:

- **Popular categories title** as a dimension.
- **Event count** as a metric.

Comment: Thank you. I have done custom dimension before, but still waiting for data. It is very bad that I have collected data for months and now I can't see it ;(

Comment: Also it a bit strange. If I have nothing in row then I can see Popular Categories and total count of events, but as soon as I add popular_categories as a row then for that combination is no data. Maybe I have to wait one two days...

Comment: Now it is working! Thanks! rows - popular_categories, span - nothing, values - Event count and filter to Event name equal Popular categories. And dimension popular_categories.